# Piecewise constant solution of waves

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, wave-equation

Please let me know if my title or notation should be changed to something more precise.

In the study of waves, I am considering eigenfunction expansions of waves on a finite interval $0 \leq x \leq L$ as products

$$y_n(x,t) = C_n \sin(kx)\sin(\omega t)$$ with a dispersion relation, $\omega = f(k)$, and where $C_n$ is the amplitude that is determined from initial conditions $y(x,0) = y_0(x)$.

Suppose $y_0(x)$ is piecewise constant on $[0,L]$, and consider the solution to our equation, $y(x,t)$. Sometimes, there exist future times $t_i >0$ where $y(x,t_i)$ is again piecewise constant, but not equal to $y_0(x)$.

For example, consider the equation on $0 \leq x \leq L$,
$$\frac{\partial^2 \Psi}{\partial x^2} = i \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$$
This has dispersion relation $\omega = c^2 k^2$. Playing around with solutions to this equation, one can see that a piecewise constant initial condition will produce piecewise constant profiles at certain later times. For example, if $$y_0(x)= \begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq \frac{L}{4} \\
      1 & \frac{L}{4} \leq x\leq \frac{L}{2}\\
      0 & \frac{L}{2} \leq x \leq L 
   \end{cases}$$

we see at later times some of the following solution profiles:

[image]

[image]

The solutions here are not exactly piecewise constant because I came across this accidentally, so could only approximate the correct times. And, of course, we see Gibbs oscillations, which prevents the solution from ever being truly constant. However, I hope the phenomenon I am describing is clear.

I have several questions here:

**(1)** *Why* does this occur??

**(2)** For what dispersion relations $\omega = f(k)$ does this occur?

**(3)** Given that $y_0(x)$ is piecewise constant, suppose there exists a time $t_1 > 0$ such that $y(t_1,x)$ is also piecewise constant. What will be the properties of $y(t_1, x)$? Is there a relationship between $\int_0^L y(t_1,x) dx$ and $\int_0^L y_0(x) dx$?

**(4)** Given that $y_0(x)$ is piecewise constant, suppose there exists a time $t_1 > 0$ such that $y(t_1,x)$ is also piecewise constant. Does this guarantee that there will exist infinitely many further times $t_2 < t_3 < ...$ with $y(x,t_i)$ piecewise constant? If so, what are these times?

I appreciate any and all help on this question!

Comment: I don´t know exactly how to answer your questions, but there is an related issue which could cause some of your problems: the wave equation is a linear differential equation (so its possible to answer it through the sum of plane waves with different frequencies), and as a linear diff. equation it is tight to uniqueness of solutions. The problem here, is that is impossible for an equation which fulfills uniqueness to have solutions that have a constant value in a compacted-supported interval of non-zero measure. (...)

Comment: It is not the same reason, but is similar to what happens with non-piecewise Power Series, which also cannot have a constant section equal to zero since if it happen to be true, it would violate the [Identity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem), which says if its zero in a compacted-supported interval of non-zero measure, then it must be the zero function in the whole domain. In the case of nonlinear differential equation, an example of having a flat section could be seen in the [Norton's Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_dome) problem.